# SCORM 2004 Error 403

Tags: javascript, scorm, scorm2004

I keep getting this error but there is nothing I can find about it on the Internet. What I am trying is get value of `cmi.location` but Chrome console and SCORM Cloud says

`Set Error State: 403 - The Location field has not been set for this SCO`

---

here is my code

```
locIdentifier = Number(scorm.get("cmi.location"));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

403: "Data Model Element Value Not Initialized"

This just means there was no value so it's not really an error.  SCORM has a few of these.

The Specification requires the Runtime API to throw that error.  I consider a few non-actionable errors within the spec which would of been handy if they were called warnings instead of errors.

If your cmi.entry is 'ab-initio' you would have no reason to request cmi.location or cmi.suspend_data for example.  It's a clean attempt.  However, some platforms fail to set cmi.entry to 'resume' when the SCO is continuing an attempt.  So you also have to watch for a '' blank entry type too.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes indeed it is ab-initio and I didn't know location is unneccessary for that condition. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Fun with latin - means  "from the beginning".

Comment: Any get that has an error is required to return an empty string - so it's also safe to get it knowing it might be blank and putting a default value in there - which also handles those annoying platforms that don't set "resume" properly ;-).